# parentheses upon creation a object

Tags: javascript, wrapper

why are we putting parentheses upon creating an object, for example, what is gonna happen if we removed the parentheses around the (new String())?

```
var upper = (new String(str)).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to use `new String(str)` anyway; `str.toUpperCase()` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point to those parentheses, `new` has high [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and the result would be exactly the same if you didn't have the parentheses there.

---

Your question applies generally (for instance, `(new Date()).toISOString()` vs. `new Date().toISOString()`), but just for what it's worth `new String(x)` in JavaScript is generally unnecessary at best or potentially a bug at worst. It creates a string *object*, whereas normally we interact with string *primitives*. The difference can matter sometimes, for example `new String("x") == new String("x")` is **`false`**, because two separate objects are never `==` to each other.

There's almost never any reason to use a string object.

That code may have been trying to defend against the possibility that `str` wasn't a string, by converting it to one. If so, remove the `new`:

```
var upper = String(str).toUpperCase();
```

`String` without `new` does a type conversion (to a string primitive).

Comment: So what you mean is parentheses is just for protection purpose not more. like the one in the IIFE

Comment: @AnasRoshdi - No, there's literally no point to them (other than to reassure people who don't realize `new` has such high precedence). (In contrast, the ones in IIFEs are usually required.)